# How to control the FFTW frequency bins and resolution

Tags: fortran, fft, fftw, spectrum

I'm writing a code to compute a simple real data transformation using FFTW. I want to compare the spectrum of the FFTW to FT of the same data. My DFT data length is 5000. However, even if I use a much larger FFTW size (for example `N=450000`) I don't get a desired frequency resolution. In other words, there's a large gap between each frequency bins in the output spectrum.

This gives me a frequency gap of 1/(deltat*N) = 1,154,700.5

Is there any way I can produce smaller frequencies without massively increasing the FFT size (`N`) which will sacrifice the speed.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that a frequency resolution of approximately `1e6` represent a tiny fraction of your `wave_frequency` of `3e9`. That said if you want to analyse or process frequencies within a small bandwidth around a given frequency of interest (such as `3e9`), then `1e6` might well represent a sizable portion of that bandwidth. The trick then is to zoom in on the frequency band of interest. This can be achieved with the following broad steps:

- Apply bandpass filter centered around the frequency of interest;
- Frequency shift the filtered signal to a lower center frequency (e.g. using Weaver SSB frequency shifting technique [described here](https://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~clark/nordmodularbook/nm_spectrum_shift.html));
- Downsample the frequency shifted signal (take one every `M` sample). This will increase `deltat`, thus resulting in a better resolution (decreased frequency difference between frequency bins) for the same FFT block size.